# Doubts about deferred execution

Tags: linq, deferred-execution

Suppose I have this :

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> StructsTemp;
```

I wrote n queries on StructsTemp, so that it populates from the DB, and so on. 
Later, I execute them calling `.ToList()` :

```
IList<MyObject> StructsFinal = StructsTemp.ToList();
... some queries on StructsFinal ....
StructsTemp = StructsFinal;
```

What about if later I do this?

```
StructsTemp.Count()
```

Will it re-execute the n queries on StructsTemp? Will this re-execute StructsTemp.ToList()? Will this re-execute all queries on StructsFinal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a reference of `List<T>` to the variable `StructsTemp`, the `IEnumerable<T> actually`**is** a `List<T>` and will use it's `Count` property instead of enumerating the underlying sequence.

```
var numbers = new []{ 1,2,3 };
IEnumerable<int>evenNumbers = numbers.Where(i=> i % 2 == 0);
// deferred, will enumerate the sequence to count the even numbers
int count = evenNumbers.Count();
evenNumbers = evenNumbers.ToList();
// not deferred, using the Count property of List<T>
count = evenNumbers.Count();
```

So the latter will always return the same value since it's persisted in a new collection. The former can return a different result on each iteration when the underlying collection has changed(f.e. `numbers.Remove(2)` causes `evenNumbers.Count` to be 0) .

**Edit**:

Here's a more meaningful demo of that behaviour: http://ideone.com/91Yrh

Comment: so evenNumbers = evenNumbers.ToList(); will "turn" an IEnumerable to a List? :O I don't think so...

Comment: @markzzz: `IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so every list is also an ienumerable implicitely. That's just inheritance. But the reference changes from a linq query which has an underlying collection to a  different `List<T>`.

Comment: That's not clear at all :) Suppose, before `int count = evenNumbers.Count();` I "cycle" evenNumbers with a foreach : what is that? Not a List<T> :O

Comment: Also : if I didnt evenNumbers = evenNumbers.ToList(); , every evenNumbers.Count(); will execute the query (where) every time?

Comment: @markzzz: I haven't understand your first comment at all(what's _cycle_?). The answer to your last coment: Yes. And that could be very expensive, understand the `Where` as an `if` in a loop.

Comment: I mean "cycling" the list with a foreach. Foreach will turn the unmaterialized list (???) into what? A Enumerable? (which is not materialized?) :O

Comment: What I also find bizzare is this : after evenNumbers = evenNumbers.ToList(); , evenNumbers become a List from "somethings that I didn't understand yet", and I can't use it properly (in fact I can't use evenNumbers.Count property, which it is allowed with List<T>). First time I see this behaviour on OP language...

Comment: @markzzz: Here's a sample which demonstrates what i mean. It prints a _"`veryExpensiveMethod`"_ 10 times. 5 for the `Where` and 5 times for the `ToList`: http://ideone.com/91Yrh After the `ToList` you could call `Count()` 1000 times without an additonal call of the _"`veryExpensiveMethod`"_.

Comment: @markzzz: You **can** use the `evenNumbers.Count` property if you want. You just have to cast it accordingly, that is what `Enumerable.Count()` also tries first before it enumerates the sequence: `((ICollection<int>)evenNumbers).Count`. But that's not necessary as i've already mentioned since `Enumerable.Count` checks it first.

Comment: Thank you! This means with .NET and "statically linked" ?

Comment: @markzzz: You're welcome, although i don't understand what you mean by _"statically linked"_. Extension methods are always static but that has nothing to do with this topic (inheritance and [`iterator blocks`](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx)).

Comment: That's also why, turn it into a list, I need .ToList() at the end if I do `nums=nums.Where(i=> veryExpensiveMethod(i))` (because, otherwise, this query will be never executed). Right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14183/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-markzzz)

Answer (score 0):

`ToList()` will force the evaluatation of `StructsTemp`, whatever that is, but it has no effect on the subsequent Linq.

`... some queries on StructsFinal ....` may or may not be lazy evaluated, lets assume it\they are.

the `Count()` extension is not lazy so would force the execution of `... some queries on StructsFinal ....`,

As an aside, if the result of `... some queries on StructsFinal ....` implements `ICollection<T>`, like `IList<T>` does, then the `Count()` extension will just access the `Count` property of the result.